# UITextField placeholderRectForBounds

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitextfield

I want to create a UITextField with the placeholder aligned to left and the text is aligned to center. I search a bit and I found placeholderRectForBounds: function the apple documents says override if you want to but doesnt say how? I tried categorize the UITextField however It wasnt a success. any one has an idea?
thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking how to make the `UITextField` use left alignment when it only has placeholder text, and switch to centre alignment when the user enters in text?

Comment: I want to set the textAligment: to Center but I also want the placeholder text appear left of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At default set the text alignment as left.

When you start typing on the textfield this delegate will be called

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //here again set the alignment value to center
    textField.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

This delegate will be called when you focus out of textfield

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  //Here check text in the textfield. if its nill set alignment as left.
  //Becoz if there is no text in textfield placeholder will be shown.
}
```